# XML layout design and code are not matching

Tags: android, xml

My xml layout design is not what it is supposed to be from my code. I am not changing anything dynamically.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rollnoT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="200sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rollnoT"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="abc"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cmtT"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Ab"
            android:textSize="200sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My design:

[image]

Look at "abc" It should be below '5' not in mid.
I have set `android:layout_below="@+id/rollnoT"`
but still it is shown in mid.

Pls help me solve this issue.

Comment: Why don't you use LinearLayout?

Comment: How can I use a LinearLayout! I have a textview in background.

Comment: Check my answer post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rollnoT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="200sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/rollnoT"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:text="abc"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cmtT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ab"
                android:textSize="200sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this blow snippet,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rollnoT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="200sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rollnoT"
                    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                    android:text="abc"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cmtT"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ab"
                android:textSize="200sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

It would be great if you have practice about `LinearLayout`. It solves lots of issues. If you are using `RelativeLayout` then it is dependable on other views.